# How do I remove background colour in a draggable HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

I'm trying to build a palette with draggable circle elements which will be dragged and dropped on a canvas. The palette color is different from the body and the canvas background.

The problem I'm facing is that there is a square background to the circular element that I'm trying to drag and drop. How do I remove that and make only the circle appear when the element is being dragged from the palette?

Here is my code:

```js
document.getElementById("drag-coveredup").addEventListener("dragstart", function (e) {
    var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(crt);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 50px, 50px);
}, false);
```

```css
body{
    background : #242424;
}
.dragdemo {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    color: #efe;
}
.bgcolor{
    background : transparent;
}
.palette{
    background: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class ="palette">
  <div class="bgcolor">
    <div id="drag-coveredup" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">
      drag me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @OmarEinea FYI I have approved your edit, except correcting `colour` to `color`. `Colour` is correct, it's the British way of writing it, and `color` is American, so I left it as colour.

Comment: It works if the `<body>`'s background color is white and all other divs transparent. Not quite exactly what wou want, because your whole document will be white, but at least you won't have a background when dragging.

Comment: Sample code does not work. Did you also try jQuery draggable plugin ?

Comment: @JeremyThille - The body Back ground is white. I want to have a div with black background with all the draggable elements lined up. So the div that holds the draggable elements has to be of a different colour than the body

Comment: The body is _not_ white. Your CSS states clearly : `body{ background : #242424; }`, which is almost black. You say `I want to have a div with black background` but in your example, said div has a white background. Make up your mind

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant I want the body to be dark grey #242424 and the div with a white background #fff which would hold all the draggable elements. Exactly what has been given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The draggable elements background "box" color will depend on the body background color and its position in the viewport.

Avoid displaying a background border around the element, set with `setDragImage`, by positioning the element outside of the current viewport e.g.

```js
dragElem.style.position = "absolute";
dragElem.style.top = "-1000px";
document.body.appendChild(dragElem);
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragElem, 0, 0);
```

Make sure you remove the element in your `dragEnd` event handler.